# Finding duplicate entries across very large text files in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I am working with very large data files extracted from a database.  There are duplicates across these files that I need to remove.  If there are duplicates they will exist across files not within the same file.  The files contain entries that look like the following:

```
File1

 623898/bn-oopi-990iu/I Like Potato
 982347/ki-jkhi-767ho/Let's go to Sesame Street
 ....


File2

 568798/jj-ytut-786hh/Hello Mike
 982347/ki-jkhi-767ho/Let's go to Sesame Street
 ....
```

So the Sesame Street line will have to be removed possibly even across 5 files but at least remain in one of them.  From what I have been able to grab so far I can perform the following `cat * | sort | uniq -cd` to give me each duplicated line and the number of times they have been duplicated.  But have no way of getting the file name. `cat * | sort | uniq -cd | grep "" *` doesn't work.  Any ideas or approaches for a solution would be great.

Comment: Can't you remove the duplicates directly in your database? SQL is rather good at expressing this kind of things.

Comment: That would be wonderful but I can't use a database for this.

Comment: Do you want to store all unique entries in a new file?

Comment: No.  Each file is an actual DB entry itself.  what I really need to do is find which files contain duplicate lines and delete the duplicate line from each file EXCEPT for one file.  @choroba has provided me with simply finding the name of files where duplicates occur.  Now I have to find the lines in those files and remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding your original idea:

```
sort * | uniq -cd | awk '{print $2}' | grep -Ff- *
```

i.e. form the output, print only the duplicate strings, then search all the files for them (list of things to search from taken form `-`, i.e. stdin), literally (`-F`).

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines might be useful:

```
awk '!seen[$0] { print $0 > FILENAME ".new" } { seen[$0] = 1 }' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

twalberg's solution works perfectly but if your files are really large it could exhaust the available memory because it creates one entry in an associative array per encountered unique record. If it happens, you can try a similar approach where there is only one entry per duplicate record (I assume you have GNU awk and your files are named *.txt):

```
sort *.txt | uniq -d > dup
awk 'BEGIN {while(getline < "dup") {dup[$0] = 1}} \
!($0 in dup) {print >> (FILENAME ".new")} \
$0 in dup {if(dup[$0] == 1) {print >> (FILENAME ".new");dup[$0] = 0}}' *.txt
```

Note that if you have many duplicates it could also exhaust the available memory. You can solve this by splitting the `dup` file in smaller chunks and run the `awk` script on each chunk.